# How to create a long lived service in Elastic Beanstalk with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, service, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to write a service or an application that sits in the Elastic Beanstalk, hooks into a RabbitMQ (also running in AWS) and listen for messages.

I am unclear how to get started.  All the examples are websites.  Is there an example of how to create a long lived service with Elastic Beanstalk somewhere that I am missing?

I am ok with either full .NET Framework or .NET core.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk won't work for this use case.

Elastic Beanstalk can do the following:

1. Manage a web application that receives and processes HTTP requests
2. Manage a worker application that listens to an SQS queue and processes messages.

You cannot create a worker type of service that will receive RabbitMQ messages.

Instead, you'll need to do the following:

1. Create your application as a daemon (if running on Linux) or Windows service.
2. Launch and run your application:

   - Run on EC2 instances, an Auto Scaling group will work, or
   - Inside ECS as a docker image.

Comment: The Elastic Beanstalk [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#supported-applications) explicitly mentions support for non-web applications: `Q: What kinds of applications are supported by AWS Elastic Beanstalk?
AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports Java, .NET, PHP, Node.js, Python, Ruby, Go, and Docker, and is ideal for web applications. However, due to Elastic Beanstalk’s open architecture, non-web applications can also be deployed using Elastic Beanstalk`

Comment: The Elastic Beanstalk docs says that web apps and background workers can be created: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html . Background workers are still web apps, but EB adds a SQS message-retrieval daemon in front of it.